# How to create a PostgreSQL table with column of type array using Fluentmigrator in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, fluent-migrator

I might be overlooking something simple, I'm pretty novice with Fluentmigrator, but is it possible to create a table, using Fluentmigrator in C# code, that has a column of type array such as TEXT []?

Here is an example using SQL Syntax for comparison of the goal, with the column 'arrt' as the target column to create:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS array_test (
    id SERIAL, 
    is_active BOOLEAN,
    arrt TEXT[]
);
```

I tried checking the list of available methods through Visual Studio intelli-sense, on the `WithColumn()` method but this isn't giving me any luck.
Also, although I am not sure I looked in the right place I did try going through the list of types [here](https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator/blob/master/src/FluentMigrator.Runner.Postgres/Generators/Postgres/PostgresTypeMap.cs), which didn't show any indications I could tell that it is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Create.Table("tablename")
                .WithColumn("columnname").AsCustom("TEXT[]").Nullable();
```

Comment: Hi @Adolf - been a little time but I'm swinging back around to this. I finally got to test this and it does work with the use of AsCustom(). So for future travelers I'm marking this. Nice one thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on link you provided and some search by myself seems like standard FluentMigrator methods can't do it.

But you can run sql script from your migration. Not the best practice, but in some cases is very helpful. [Here you can see some examples](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/fluent-interface.html). Execute Expression section.

```
Execute.Script("myscript.sql");
Execute.EmbeddedScript("UpdateLegacySP.sql");
Execute.Sql("DELETE TABLE Users");
```

Also you can make branch from FluentMigrator repo and add this methods by yourself. But it will be hard to handle new official updates.

Comment: For the moment I am in fact going the script route, but I had also hoped for just a better approach. Still, you confirmed what I thought too and I appreciate your help and time on it. 
I like the idea of may be extending it in my own branch, if time allows that could be a fun project to try. Cheers

Comment: The answer by Adolf does in fact fit the bill. I still ended up with a custom script as noted, but I wanted to also add in here that it looks like it is possible without too :)